# Get remaining height on page (and scale image to it)

Tags: graphics, spacing, page-breaking

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to define a figure size so that is consume the rest of a page?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14512/how-to-define-a-figure-size-so-that-is-consume-the-rest-of-a-page)

Hi all,

I've seen [How to compute the remaining space on the current page](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/4017/how-to-compute-the-remaining-space-on-the-current-page) - but that doesn't really address what I want to do.

Say, I type, I type, and then I insert an image - and in a lot of cases I usually want to enter images "here"; and there seems to be some blank space on the bottom of the page. So I do :

```
... blah blah blah.... 

\begin{figure}[h]
\centering
\includegraphics[width=0.8\textwidth]{../path/to/image.png}
\caption{Some caption here}
\label{fig:somelabel}
\end{figure}
```

... and more often than note, image will take up more vertical space than what is remaining on page, and LaTeX will push it onto the next page, which I hate :) Because then, I have to manually change values, to `width=0.7\textwidth`, then `width=0.6\textwidth`, then `width=0.5\textwidth`, then `width=0.55\textwidth` - each of these requiring a new recompile - to finally discover that it is for `0.55\textwidth`, that the height of the image is such, that it fits (along with caption) in the remaining bottom space of the page, and finally get the image where I want.

Basically - what I'd like is some macro, so that instead of scaling the width as in `[width=0.8\textwidth]` - I would scale the height according to remaining space, as in this (pseudo) example:

```
\includegraphics[height=0.9\RemainingVerticalSpaceOnPage]{../path/to/image.png}
```

... which utilizes the (imaginary) `\RemainingVerticalSpaceOnPage` macro.

So my question is: Does anything resembling this `\RemainingVerticalSpaceOnPage` exist?

Thanks in advance for any answers,
Cheers!

Comment: See [How to define a figure size so that is consume the rest of a page?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/14512/2975).

Comment: Awesome - thanks @Martin Scharrer! (Btw, I would have never formulated the question in that way - probably why I missed it in my search)... Well, I guess that answers the question - if you want, post an answer so I can accept it :) Thanks - cheers!

Comment: Not problem. I marked it as duplicate, so your formulation now also points to the solution.