# Scale tikzpicture to the remaining height of a beamer frame

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer, scaling

Often in a `frame` (of `beamer`), I have some texts on the top and a resized `tikzpicture` on the bottom:

```
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{...}
some texts
...
some texts
\[\resizebox{!}{???}{
\begin{tikzpicture}
...
\end{tikzpicture}
}\]
\end{frame}
```

I am wondering how to determine the `???` part, to make the `tikzpicture` occupy the remaining part of the `frame`, so that the total *height* of picture plus text occupies the whole `frame`.

Does anyone know how to do that?

Comment: An inherent hurdle here is that `beamer` frames have their content vertically centred. Consequently, you'll have to typeset something flush to the bottom in order to obtain the remaining height of the frame. Moreover, `\pagegoal` and `\pagetotal` don't seem to be of help here in order to calculate the remaining "page" height.

Comment: Related questions are [How to define a figure size so that it consumes the rest of a page?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14512/how-to-define-a-figure-size-so-that-it-consumes-the-rest-of-a-page) and [How to compute the remaining space on the current page](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/4017/how-to-compute-the-remaining-space-on-the-current-page). Both use `\pagegoal` and `\pagetotal` but I trust @Werner when he says they don't work with `beamer`, which changes a lot of TeX internals.

Comment: Did me answer work for you? If not please state what is still missing. Otherwise please consider accepting it. Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `zref` to measure the remaining space by saving the bottom position of the text and the one of the bottom of the frame. The following code works for me. It requires two runs after each change of text. It seems to work well
with different themes. If you want the image centered uncomment the `\centering`. I added a lower margin to not have it touch the bottom edge. You could also use a `center` environment which adds (rather large IMHO) margins by itself if you want.

Note that the environment `restofframe` can be used multiple times and all instances on one slide will share the remaining space equally.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Berlin}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{zref-savepos}

\newcounter{restofframe}
\newsavebox{\restofframebox}
\newlength{\mylowermargin}
\setlength{\mylowermargin}{2pt}

\newenvironment{restofframe}{%
    \par%\centering
    \stepcounter{restofframe}%
    \zsavepos{restofframe-\arabic{restofframe}-begin}%
    \begin{lrbox}{\restofframebox}%
}{%
    \end{lrbox}%
    \setkeys{Gin}{keepaspectratio}%
    \raisebox{\dimexpr-\height+\ht\strutbox\relax}[0pt][0pt]{%
    \resizebox*{!}{\dimexpr\zposy{restofframe-\arabic{restofframe}-begin}sp-\zposy{restofframe-\arabic{restofframe}-end}sp-\mylowermargin\relax}%
        {\usebox{\restofframebox}}%
    }%
    \vskip0pt plus 1filll\relax
    \mbox{\zsavepos{restofframe-\arabic{restofframe}-end}}%
    \par
}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Title}
some texts

some texts

some text

some text

\begin{restofframe}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw (0,0) -- (1,1);
    \draw (0,1) -- (1,0);
\end{tikzpicture}%
\end{restofframe}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Title}
\framesubtitle{Subtitle}
some texts

some texts

some text

some text

\begin{restofframe}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw (0,0) -- (1,1);
    \draw (0,1) -- (1,0);
\end{tikzpicture}%
\end{restofframe}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Title}
\framesubtitle{Subtitle}
some texts

some texts

\begin{restofframe}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw (0,0) -- (1,1);
    \draw (0,1) -- (1,0);
\end{tikzpicture}%
\end{restofframe}

some text

some text

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image: Result]

Comment: +1 Super! `zref` is awezome.