# How to obtain the space left to bottom of page

Tags: spacing, vertical-alignment, framed

Since it is impossible to use `\vfill` inside a `framebox`, is there any way of getting the current height position of text? I want to fill in a `framebox` so that it uses all the space left on a page, instead of trial and error...

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx). A tip: If you indent lines by 4 spaces, then they're marked as a code sample. You can also highlight the code and click the "code" button (`{}`).

Comment: Also, you can use backticks `\`` to [mark your inline code](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/863).

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to compute the remaining space on the current page](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/4017/how-to-compute-the-remaining-space-on-the-current-page)

Comment: Check out [http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/17813/22413].

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to define a figure size so that it consumes the rest of a page?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14512/how-to-define-a-figure-size-so-that-it-consumes-the-rest-of-a-page)

Comment: I don't think that this is a duplicate since the implementation of the linked posts to `\framebox` is not that direct (and obvious to *everyone*).

Answer (score 1):

### Is there any way of getting the current height position of text?

If this were your only question, then you have the answer in Aditya's `\measurepage` in [**How to define a figure size so that it consumes the rest of a page?**](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14512/how-to-define-a-figure-size-so-that-it-consumes-the-rest-of-a-page)

I don't consider your question as duplicate though since it is specific to using `\framebox` which cannot take a macro directly as height using `\framebox(<width>,<height>){<>}` syntax. A possibility using Aditya's `\measurepage` macro is to use `\parbox` as in the `MWE` below.

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newcommand\measurepage{\dimexpr\pagegoal-\pagetotal-\baselineskip\relax}
\newcommand{\MyFrameBox}[1]{%
{\addtolength{\linewidth}{%-\marginparsep
-9.5pt}
\noindent
\framebox{
\parbox[t][\measurepage]{\linewidth}{
#1
}}}}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-2]

\MyFrameBox{\lipsum[1]}
%
%Here is the next text
\end{document}
```

The `showframe` option of the `geometry` was just used here so that you can see where the text ends.