# Making a breakable empty box in exam class

Tags: boxes, exam

In the following MWE, the empty box appears in the second page because it doesn't fit the first one:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{exam}
\begin{document}
\begin{questions}
    \question
        Text
        \makeemptybox{50\baselineskip}
\end{questions}
\end{document}
```

I would like the box to begin in page 1 and to end in page 2.

How can I do that?

Comment: Maybe with package `framed`?

Comment: As a rule, boxes can't be split across pages.  If you knew how much space was left on the page, you could use two separate boxes.  See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/88297/how-to-obtain-the-space-left-to-bottom-of-page?r=SearchResults&s=4|53.5472

Comment: IIRC,tcolorbox has a breakable box.  Of course, `\vspace{60\baselineskip}` is not breakable either.